# How to Find the Database Views Which are not executed or Accessed for more than 6 Months in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, view, database-cleaner

I would like to clean up my database by identified & removing the views & stored procedures which were not in use or not accessed for a longer period (May be for last 6 months or 1 year) in SQL Server 2005.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any statistic, trace, historical information stored anywhere that would give detail about their usage ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this 100% unless you're running a trace on your system 24/7 and keeping the data or using the auditing mechanisms of 2008.

All the data will be lost when you restart system, else you can find out the last used time for a specific object as queried below

```
select 
    DB_NAME(us.[database_id]) as [db], 
    OBJECT_NAME(us.[object_id],us.[database_id]) as [object], 
    MAX(us.[last_user_lookup]) as [last_user_lookup], 
    MAX(us.[last_user_scan]) as [last_user_scan], 
    MAX(us.[last_user_seek]) as [last_user_seek] 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats us 
where us.[database_id] = DB_ID() 
    AND us.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tblname')
group by us.[database_id], us.[object_id];
```

Comment: This is the better answer

Comment: i think that query which you have given will work on SQL Server 2008, when i try the same it says OBJECT_NAME requires 1 argument(s). Can you help me with this in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Koushick's answer, I resolved it by using this ..

```
SELECT DB_NAME(us.[database_id]) AS [db],
       OBJECT_NAME(us.[object_id], us.[database_id]) AS [object],
       MAX(us.[last_user_lookup]) AS [last_user_lookup],
       MAX(us.[last_user_scan]) AS [last_user_scan],
       MAX(us.[last_user_seek]) AS [last_user_seek]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS us
WHERE DB_NAME(us.[database_id]) = 'your database name'
  AND OBJECT_NAME(us.[object_id], us.[database_id]) = 'your object'
GROUP BY us.[database_id], us.[object_id];
```

You can then quickly sort and play with the dates to see when objects were last used, as opposed to when they were last **modified**.

Comment: i think that query which you have given will work on SQL Server 2008, when i try the same it says OBJECT_NAME requires 1 argument(s). Can you help me with this in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Hi @ManoBharath. I ran the above exactly as is in Sql server 2005 fine.

Answer (score -1):

To find out the views/stored procedures older than particular date you can use following query

```
SELECT [name],create_date,modify_date
FROM sys.views (or sys.procedures) 
WHERE modify_date<= 'date_older_than_you_want'
```

To find out unused views you can use following query:

```
   SELECT [name],create_date,modify_date
   FROM
        sys.views
   where create_date=modify_date
```

Comment: This only shows views (or procedures using sys.procedures) that have not been modified since they were created. It does not have anything to do with showing when the view was last used or if used at all.